# How to load javascript values in html page

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script code where i will get a array list, then i have iterated and got each one in a variable. Now my requirement is to show this values in my html page which i have designed. I have to load the retried values in my page. The imageurl should be given inside the img src to show that image. Plus this should be dynamically incremented.

```js
 <script>
  function getValueFromServer(e) {
  //make the AJAX request to server
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example./../getAllBrandList",
    dataType: "json",
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function( data) {
      console.log(data);
      var brands=data;
      var i = 0
      //our country code was correct so we have some information to display
      for ( var i = 0; i < brands.allBrands.length; i++) {
        var obj = brands.allBrands[i];
        console.log(obj);
        var fundedType= "LIVE";
        var url=obj.url;
        var imageUrl=obj.image_url;
        var brandName=obj.brandName;
        var description=obj.description;
        var totalGoal=obj.total_goal;
        var totalRaised=obj.total_raised;
        var profitMargin=obj.profit_margin;
         }
    },
    //If there was no resonse from the server
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
      $("#ajaxResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    //capture the request before it was sent to server
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
    //adding some Dummy data to the request
                    settings.data += "&dummyData=whatever";
                    //disable the button until we get the response
                    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", true);
                },
                
                //this is called after the response or error functions are finsihed
                //so that we can take some action
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    //enable the button 
                    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", false);
                }
      
            });        
    };
window.onload = getValueFromServer();
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="small-12 columns" onload="getValueFromServer()">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3" id="brands">
      <!-- <li class="item" >
        <a href="" class="badge-live" data-badge="LIVE" ></a>
        <a href=""><div class="offer">

            <span class="link-overlay"></span>

          <img src="" id="imageurl">
          <div class="offer-info">
            <h6 id="brandname"></h6>
            <p class="offer-short" id="description"></p>
            <p class="funded">
              <span class="goal">
                <strong id="totalgoal">$</strong> raised 1 day ago in 13 minutes
              </span>
            </p>
            <div class="nice round progress"><span class="meter-reserved" style="width: 100%;"></span><span class="meter" style="width: 100%;"></span></div>
            <div class="row offer-stats">
              <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
                <p>
                  <span id="profitmargin">%</span> Co-Op Profit Margin
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="margin:0.5rem 0 1rem;">
            <div class="row text-center offer-stats">
              <div class="small-6 columns">
                <p>
                  <span>96</span>following
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="small-6 columns" style="border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;">
                <p>
                  <span>4</span>Months
                </p>
              </div>
            </div></a>
             <div class="text-center">
              <a href="http://localhost/sample/signup.html" class="button radius offers-button color:black">GET STARTED</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li> -->
      
     
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see a piece of code which is generating HTML. You are just iterating the values which cames from ajax request. Where it is, where are you creating DOM elements?

Comment: Dude, if your main goal is to send javascript values to the view and even change it dinamycally without having to touch to the DOM, but only by changing the original value for the new one, then you should REALLY take a look at AngularJS, that's one of it's main purposes even if he can do much more than that, that's a very cool framework (you can also take a look at ReactJS, but i think you should begin by Angular) here is a *valid link: https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

not tested but should work using `innerHTML` to write list to `brands` ul

```js
  function getValueFromServer(e) {
  //make the AJAX request to server
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example./../getAllBrandList",
    dataType: "json",
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function( data) {
      console.log(data);
      var brands=data;
      var i = 0
      //our country code was correct so we have some information to display
      for ( var i = 0; i < brands.allBrands.length; i++) {
        var obj = brands.allBrands[i];
        console.log(obj);
        var fundedType= "LIVE";
        var url=obj.url;
        var imageUrl=obj.image_url;
        var brandName=obj.brandName;
        var description=obj.description;
        var totalGoal=obj.total_goal;
        var totalRaised=obj.total_raised;
        var profitMargin=obj.profit_margin;

document.getElementById("brands").innerHTML +=  '<li class="item" >\
        <a href="" class="badge-live" data-badge="LIVE" ></a>\
        <a href=""><div class="offer">\
            <span class="link-overlay"></span>\
          <img src="'+imageUrl+'" id="imageurl">\
          <div class="offer-info">\
            <h6 id="brandname">'+brandName+'</h6>\
            <p class="offer-short" id="description">'+description+'</p>\
            <p class="funded">\
              <span class="goal">\
                <strong id="totalgoal">$'+totalGoal+'</strong> raised 1 day ago in 13 minutes\
              </span>\
            </p>\
            <div class="nice round progress"><span class="meter-reserved" style="width: 100%;"></span><span class="meter" style="width: 100%;"></span></div>\
            <div class="row offer-stats">\
              <div class="small-12 columns text-center">\
                <p>\
                  <span id="profitmargin">%'+profitMargin+'</span> Co-Op Profit Margin\
                </p>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
            <hr style="margin:0.5rem 0 1rem;">\
            <div class="row text-center offer-stats">\
              <div class="small-6 columns">\
                <p>\
                  <span>96</span>following\
                </p>\
              </div>\
              <div class="small-6 columns" style="border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;">\
                <p>\
                  <span>4</span>Months\
                </p>\
              </div>\
            </div></a>\
             <div class="text-center">\
              <a href="http://localhost/sample/signup.html"\ class="button radius offers-button color:black">GET\ STARTED</a>\
            </div>\
          </div>\
        </div>\
      </li>';
         }
    },
    //If there was no resonse from the server
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
      $("#ajaxResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    //capture the request before it was sent to server
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
    //adding some Dummy data to the request
                    settings.data += "&dummyData=whatever";
                    //disable the button until we get the response
                    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", true);
                },
                
                //this is called after the response or error functions are finsihed
                //so that we can take some action
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    //enable the button 
                    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", false);
                }
      
            });        
    };
window.onload = getValueFromServer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-12 columns" onload="getValueFromServer()">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3" id="brands">

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: glad to hear this